# Extract Positive and Negative float values in raw text file using Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, dataframe, text-extraction, data-extraction

So I'm trying to extract certain values from a raw text file like this

```
Number of zero columns: 4
Memory requirement - global matrix: 1571340 solver (totally): 1571340
P1127_VELOCITIES #001000  Step:    59  Iteration:     2  Time:    0.04055  0.0015347 
P2243_VELOCITIES #001000  Step:    59  Iteration:     2  Time:    0.04055  0.0017193 
P3387_VELOCITIES #001000  Step:    59  Iteration:     2  Time:    0.04055  0.0015347 
% of load in interval  Step:    59  Iteration:     2  Time:    0.04055  0.0400000  0.0400000 
summation % of load in interval  Step:    59  Iteration:     2  Time:    0.04055  0.0800000 

Number of zero columns: 4
Memory requirement - global matrix: 1571340 solver (totally): 1571340
P1127_VELOCITIES #001000  Step:    59  Iteration:     2  Time:    0.01638 -0.0016876 
P2243_VELOCITIES #001000  Step:    59  Iteration:     2  Time:    0.01638 -0.0018896 
P3387_VELOCITIES #001000  Step:    59  Iteration:     2  Time:    0.01638 -0.0016876 
% of load in interval  Step:    59  Iteration:     2  Time:    0.01638  0.0400000  0.0400000 
summation % of load in interval  Step:    59  Iteration:     2  Time:    0.01638  0.0800000
```

So I want to extract `P1127_VELOCITIES` by using this code:

```
P1127_positive = re.compile(r'P1127_VELOCITIES #001000  Step:    (\d+)  Iteration:     (\d+)  Time:    (\d+\.\d+)  (\d*\.\d+|-\d*\.\d+)')

P1127_negative = re.compile(r'P1125_VELOCITIES #001000  Step:    (\d+)  Iteration:     (\d+)  Time:    (\d+\.\d+) (\d*\.\d+|-\d*\.\d+)')


def Extract_Data(filepath, expression_positive, expression_negative, data):

    velocity_list = []
    time_list = []
    #negative_data = []

    with open(filepath) as file:
        for line in file:
            data.extend(expression_positive.findall(line))

    with open(filepath) as file:
        for line in file:
            data.extend(expression_negative.findall(line))
    print(data[0])
    print(data[1])
    for data_tuple in data:
        step, iteration, time, velocity = data_tuple
        velocity_list.append(float(velocity))
        time_list.append(float(time))



    return velocity_list, time_list
```

However, I want to extract all float values at the right end, not positive and negative values separately. As you can see in the text file, the positive values have 2 spaces (i.e. `Time:    0.04055[space][space]0.0015347` while the negative values only have 1 space (i.e.`Time:    0.01638[space]-0.0016876`)

Is there a way to extract both values using re.compile? (like what I have above but extract both). What expressions would you recommend? (i.e. `([-+]?\d\.\d+)`)

Cheers!

Comment: just do `re.findall(r"(?m)P112[57].*\s(-?\d\S+)\s*$",file.read())`

Comment: Hi ggorlen, I want to extract velocities (P1127, P2243, etc.) from some text files and I want to extract all values from them. An example of a line I want to extract is: ```P1127_VELOCITIES #001000  Step:    59  Iteration:     2  Time:    0.02419 -0.0010204 ```

Comment: @Tan Phan what exactly is the problem you are facing? Which line is velocity? which one is time? why do you need negative and positive differently? Cant you just extract both of them into one list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regexes in the provided code seem like overkill for the file you've provided. I don't see any reason for them to be so rigid that changing one character requires a new pattern. It doesn't seem like there'll be enough minute variation in the file to be quite so specific about the number of spaces and formatting in a line.

This snippet does the job cleanly on the file you've shared (I'm using `append` rather than `extend` so that each row's time pair is preserved). It's simple to add more requirements to match lines more specifically as needed (if you wish to specify a step or iteration, for example). You can also build the regex pattern dynamically if you'd like to drop this into a function and use it to filter by different velocity values.

```
import re

pattern = r"P1127_VELOCITIES.+?Time:\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$" 
data = []

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.match(pattern, line)

        if m: 
            data.append(tuple(map(float, m.groups())))

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[(0.04055, 0.0015347), (0.01638, -0.0016876)]
```

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out. I was worried the file had a ton of edge cases you were trying to avoid, but if it's well-formatted then we can just roll with a simple match on spaces and non-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now :

You match positive values using:

`(\d+\.\d+)  (\d*\.\d+|-\d*\.\d+)')` (2 spaces between the groups)

You match negative values using:

`(\d+\.\d+) (\d*\.\d+|-\d*\.\d+)')` (one space between the groups)

What you can do is use [space]{1,2} to match 1 or 2 spaces.

Like this:

`(\d+\.\d+) {1,2}(\d*\.\d+|-\d*\.\d+)`

You can test it live here: https://regex101.com/r/Cz1YJ2/1